# pip install ppaquette-gym-doom

Tags: python, pip

I wrote `pip install ppaquette-gym-doom`
and it gives me a
`error: legacy:install-failure`

I tried `pip install gensim` `pip install dlib` `--pre` `python -m pip install --upgrade pillow`
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `python -m pip isntall --upgrade wheel`
those codes didnt solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with gym-doom but based on some quick research it looks like you are getting this error because "ppaquette-gym-doom" is an obsolete version. From the github page "Note: This environment is not maintained anymore, and uses an old version of VizDoom."

It seems like the new version is simply "pip install gym-doom". This will also require something called Vizdoom.

Again this is based on quick research. I have never used these libraries.